# ServiceStack + .NET Core + Kestrel = Swagger (OpenAPI) not working

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I am trying to create a ServiceStack REST API project.  So far I have everything working except Swagger (OpenAPI).  When I load the Swagger UI it shows no APIs and I can see from the /openapi endpoint that there are no APIs discovered.

The /metadata endpoint is working fine, except for the "Swagger UI" link.

I have cut the code to the minimum:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi;
using ServiceStack.Host.Handlers;

namespace ApiTest
{
    class Program {

        [Route("/hello/{Name}", "GET", Summary = @"Hello somebody", Notes = @"Welcomes the caller")]
        public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse> {
            [ApiMember(Name="Name", Description = "Name of the caller", IsRequired = true)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class HelloResponse {
            public string Result { get; set; }
        }

        public class HelloService : Service
        {
            public object Any(Hello request) 
            {
                return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
            }
        }

        //Define the Web Services AppHost
        public class AppHost : AppHostBase {
            public AppHost() 
            : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) {
                Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature());
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }

        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());
                app.Use(new RequestInfoHandler());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

BTW here is my project file; also kept to a bare minimum:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreSources>https://www.myget.org/F/servicestack;$(RestoreSources)</RestoreSources>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Common.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Client.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Kestrel">
      <Version>1.0.*</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ServiceStack with .NET Core 2.0 we recommend using the [pre-release MyGet packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) which has explicit support for .NET Core 2.0.

Also `SwaggerFeature` implements the older 1.2 spec, new projects should be using the new [OpenApiFeature which implements the newer Swagger/OpenApi 2.0 spec](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi).

Comment: How can I get the newer packages without NuGet?  I am using VS Code on a Mac and would prefer not to have to mess with full visual studio.

Comment: @TomKludy add [the ServiceStack MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget#adding-myget-feed-without-vsnet) to your NuGet.config and place it in the root folder of your project.

Comment: OK.  Updated to the pre-release MyGet packages, and switched to OpenApiFeature.  Getting warnings about using DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 instead of 1.1.1, but otherwise builds and runs.  Now, the swagger UI gets past the "fetching resource list" but still shows no APIs.  The /openapi endpoint returns lots of properties but no API definitions.  My code is unchanged from what I posted (other than using OpenApiFeature instead of SwaggerFeature).

Comment: @TomKludy don't use `AppHostHttpListenerBase` that's for HttpListener, I'm surprised that would even start. Use [AppHostBase for .NET Core and ASP.NET](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-apphost-integration).

Comment: Switched to use AppHostBase.  The results are unfortunately the same.

Comment: @TomKludy It's something else then, we've not had any issues with it. Try starting from a simple [.NET Core 2.0 Todos App](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Todos) which I've just configured with `OpenApiFeature` that's just finished deploying over at: http://todos.netcore.io/swagger-ui/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mythz and comparing to the sample project he provided, I uncovered the problem.  In my code I was putting my DTO classes inside of the Program class; i.e. my DTO class was ApiTest.Program.Hello. When I changed my code around so that the DTOs are top-level (only inside the namespace and not inside another class) then Swagger started working.

Thank you very much @mythz for your quick response and help in this matter!